# How to get values in TensorArray which contain vary shape tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get a TensorArray that contain a list of vary shape tensors through `tf.while_loop()`, but I don't know how to get them as a normal list with tensors.

For example:

```
TensorArray([[1,2], [1,2,3], ...]) -> [Tensor([1,2]), Tensor([1,2,3]), ...]
```

```py
res = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
res = res.write(0, (1, 2))
res = res.write(0, (1, 2, 3))
with tf.Session() as sess:                                                        
     print sess.run(res.stack())
```

I get the error message in `sess.run(res.stack())`

> TensorArray has inconsistent shapes.  Index 0 has shape: [2] but index 1 has shape: [3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot make a list of the tensors in a tensor array because its size is only known on graph execution. However, if you know the size in advance, you can just make a list of the read operations yourself:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    res = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
    res = res.write(0, (1, 2))
    res = res.write(1, (1, 2, 3))
    print(res.size()) # Value only known on graph execution
    # Tensor("TensorArraySizeV3:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
    # Can make a list if the size is known in advance
    tensors = [res.read(i) for i in range(2)]
    print(tensors)
    # [<tf.Tensor 'TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'TensorArrayReadV3_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>]
    print(sess.run(tensors))
    # [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Otherwise, you can still use a while loop to iterate the tensor array. For example, you can print its contents like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    res = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
    res = res.write(0, (1, 2))
    res = res.write(1, (1, 2, 3))
    def loop_body(i, res):
        # Must import the following in Python 2:
        # from __future__ import print_function
        with tf.control_dependencies([tf.print(res.read(i))]):
            return i + 1, res
    i, res = tf.while_loop(
        lambda i, res: i < res.size(),
        loop_body,
        (tf.constant(0, tf.int32), res))
    print(sess.run(i))
    # [1 2]
    # [1 2 3]
    # 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I don't know the size in advance. So, Instead of using these tensors within `tf.while_loop`, is there no way to get the list of tensors (`[Tensor([1, 2]), Tensor([1, 2, 3])]`)?

Comment: @qingping I mean if the number of elements can change depending on the input, then a list is not possible, because you cannot know the number of elements in it. If the number of elements is always going to be the same but you do not have the number, I suppose you could do something like `with tf.Session() as sess: actual_size = sess.run(res.size())`, and once you have that then `res_elems = [res.read(i) for i in range(actual_size)]`.